# Aggregate one field and pick up the latest value of another field

Tags: sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have data like following. I want to aggregate over the interest field while pick up the latest values of Balance, Description and Date.

**Data**

```
Date    || AccNum||ID                     ||Balance ||Curncy||Interest||Description
========||=======||=======================||========||======||========||===========
7/1/2017|| DEPA1 ||HKGCIFSRCKEY002DEPA1SGD||1000    ||SGD   ||0       ||Open
8/1/2017|| DEPA1 ||HKGCIFSRCKEY002DEPA1SGD||1010    ||SGD   ||10      ||Open
9/1/2017|| DEPA1 ||HKGCIFSRCKEY002DEPA1SGD||1020    ||SGD   ||10      ||Closed
6/1/2017|| DEPA2 ||HKGCIFSRCKEY002DEPA2SGD||10000   ||SGD   ||0       ||Open
7/1/2017|| DEPA2 ||HKGCIFSRCKEY002DEPA2SGD||10100   ||SGD   ||100     ||Open
8/1/2017|| DEPA2 ||HKGCIFSRCKEY002DEPA2SGD||10200   ||SGD   ||100     ||Open
9/1/2017|| DEPA2 ||HKGCIFSRCKEY002DEPA2SGD||10300   ||SGD   ||100     ||Dormant
```

**Expected Result**

```
Date    || AccNum||ID                     ||Balance ||Curncy||Interest||Description
========||=======||=======================||========||======||========||===========
9/1/2017|| DEPA1 ||HKGCIFSRCKEY002DEPA1SGD||1020    ||SGD   ||20      ||Closed
9/1/2017|| DEPA2 ||HKGCIFSRCKEY002DEPA2SGD||10300   ||SGD   ||300     ||Dormant
```

I have about 30M records to be processed so performance is also a challenge.

Comment: Why are you showing the 7/1/2017 date in the expected results for DEPA1? Should it not be 9/1/2017 as that is the latest data for that account?

Comment: Thanks @Eli! Corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yet another option is with the **WITH TIES** clause

**Example**

```
Select Top 1 with Ties
      Date
     ,AccNum
     ,ID
     ,Balance
     ,Curncy
     ,Interest = sum(Interest) over (Partition By AccNum,ID)
     ,Description
 From YourTable
 Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By AccNum,ID Order By Date Desc)
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: This would seem to be preferred over my answer, which uses an extra subquery.  And if you wanted to select ties for each account, you could just order by using a rank function instead of row number +1.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks.  I saw your comment regarding RANK vs ROW_NUMBER.  You are correct, but it depends on how OP will use the results.  RN would avoid double counting.. Anyway already +1 for the RANK comment/distinction.

Answer (score 3):

We can use two windows functions, `SUM` and `DENSE_RANK`, to get the output you want.  The interest can summed over each account, while the rank of each record in an account can be assigned.  Then, just retain the record from each group having the most recent date.

```
SELECT
    t.Date, t.AccNum, t.ID, t.Balance, t.Curncy, t.Interest, t.Description
FROM
(
    SELECT Date, AccNum, ID, Balance, Curncy, Description,
        SUM(Interest) OVER (PARTITION BY AccNum) AS Interest,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY AccNum ORDER BY Date DESC) rank
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE t.rank = 1;
```

Most of the time on Stack Overflow you would probably see `ROW_NUMBER` being used instead of `RANK`.  I prefer to use some sort of rank in the event that two records be tied as being the most recent.  It is easy to throw away information you don't want, e.g. one of the ties, but difficult to bring it in if not already there.

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester